# Path to asset file shows "Template not found!"

Tags: craft3, assets, routing

I have a headless Craft CMS site and now the frontend development should start.

I have absolutely no frontend or templates as I only worked on the backend.

The asset url got created at `/images`. If for example the file `1.jpg` got uploaded it should be shown in `example.com/images/1.jpg` when I click on `view` in the file manager in Craft.

Sadly I get the error `Template not found` when I only want to see the uploaded file or rather get access to the file.

What can I do to get access to the assets from my asset link `/images`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your asset volume settings?

Comment: Hey, I've already read that my asset folder has to be public. I had the storage folder for my media uploads, someone suggested that I either symlink it to the web folder or use the web folder for uploads. Could that be the fix?

Comment: Yes, you should try that. For example if you store your assets in _craft/web/media/images_, you'll need to set the **File system path** of your volume to `@webroot/media/images` and its base URL to `@web/media/images`.